# Can a field change during the execution of a MySQL query and both values be present in the result set?

Tags: php, mysql

I've come across some odd defensive code. Basically it does a query like this:

```
select * from A join B on (A.b_id=B.id)
```

Then it iterates through the result set and whenever it meets a new row from table `B`, it caches it (by id). Afterwards only the cached copy is used, even for subsequent rows.

It looks like it was trying to safeguard against a result set like this:

```
 A.id | A.value | B.id | B.value
------+---------+------+---------
 1    | First   | 1    | Yay
 2    | Second  | 1    | Nay
```

But is this even possible? Even if the row in table `B` is updated while the `select` query is fetched half way, will it really be visible? Can the update even proceed while someone is querying the table?

For what it's worth, I think the table at the time was MyISAM, although it's been since converted to InnoDB. Also, the code which is running the query is written in PHP. As far as I can tell, it uses the default transaction isolation level and fetch mode.

---

OK, it seems I need some clarifications. Here's a code, similar to what I've found:

```
$sql = "select A.id a_id, A.value a_value, B.id b_id, B.value b_value from A join B on (A.b_id=B.id)";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$cacheB = array();
$A = new classA();
$B = new classB();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $A->setData($row);
    if ( !isset($cacheB[$row['b_id']]) ) {
        $cacheB[$row['b_id']] = $row;
    }
    $B->setData($cacheB[$row['b_id']]);

    // Do some processing depending on $A and $B
}
```

This code is a CLI application running from a cron job. The data from `$A` and `$B` isn't returned to anything, but depending on the contents, some external services may be called and some other DB tables may be modified. The contents of `classA`, `classB` and the processing are not relevant to this question.

My question is - is there a point for this "safeguard", or is it a deadweight that can be deleted? Let's assume that the processing part would actually be sensitive to a change in the values of `B` (although in reality I doubt it, but still).

Comment: I think you should provide more code. But if you get a dataset from db to your frontend unless you have a "live" cursor the changes in db wont affect the cursor

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - Well, I've pretty much written all the relevant parts. I can put it in code, if it's easier to understand that way, but there won't be anything new.

Comment: As I said, depend on how you get the result set. For example in angular I have to create a service to update any changes on the db be reflected on the page. And again you say some `defensive code` and iterate `throught the result` but dont show any code. So there are relevant parts still missing.

Comment: consider locking the table and possibly [flush](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/flush.html)'ing it, if that's what the question's  about.

Comment: Well, here's a clarification. Hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. But `$res` doesn't get updated if your db changes? So I don't think that is to protect from changes in `B`.  I think is to optimize the assignment and don't have to create the array `$B` multiple times.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - Ermm... I fail again. :P This particular detail is only in this example. I thought I would make it clearer. In reality, it just reuses `$row` both for `$A` and `$B`. Also, `$A` and `$B` are wrapper objects around `$row`, so instead of `$A=array(...);` the actual code reads like `$A->setData($row);` which in turns sets a private member `$this->data=$row;`. I though all this would be unnecessary for the simplified example. :P

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what that mean. You should write a proper example so we don't have to guess. You have enough rep to know how to make a better question.

Comment: btw those extension are already obsolete, you should consider change it. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - I know they're obsolete, it's an old piece of code. That's not what the question is about. OK, I'll try to improve the example. Is this better now?

Comment: I know and that is why that was my 5th comment :P. I think my 3rd comment still apply, I don't think that cache provide any use. As I said `$res` doesn't change so there is no point in save it on a `$cache`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - OK, great, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can a field change during the execution of a MySQL query and both values be present in the result set?

No.

- In MyISAM the entire table is locked by each query, so it's not possible at all, by design (see [table locking](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/table-locking.html)).
- In InnoDB queries are isolated and a select is a *consistent read* as mentioned in the doc [Locks Set by Different SQL Statements in InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locks-set.html). A *consistent read* is defined as "*A read operation that uses snapshot information to present query results based on a point in time, regardless of changes performed by other transactions running at the same time.*"

> Even if the row in table B is updated while the select query is fetched half way, will it really be visible?

Yes, even then, it's impossible.

> Can the update even proceed while someone is querying the table?

In MyISAM no, it'll have to wait, as explain in the doc: "*Table locking enables many sessions to read from a table at the same time, but if a session wants to write to a table, it must first get exclusive access, meaning it might have to wait for other sessions to finish with the table first. During the update, all other sessions that want to access this particular table must wait until the update is done.*"

In InnoDB yes, but the queries are isolated and work on different "snapshot" of the database as explained, so it doesn't matter. Transactions are particularly useful in this case if you have any doubt by the way.

The code you are showing might or might not have another purpose, this I can't say. But if the only purpose it to prevent something that *cannot* happen to happen, then it's completely redundant and can be safely removed.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case:

Right now in your while loop you have a row

```
{ a_id1, a_value1, b_id1, b_value1 }
```

And you set `$B` and save in the cache the whole row not just the values from B.

so next row in the loop will have a different `a_id`, but `same b_id`

```
{ a_id2, a_value2, b_id1, b_value1 }
```

But in this case you will set `$B` using the cached version of $row so you will have `a_id1` instead of `a_id2`

My guess is `$B->setData()` only care about fields related to `B` so using the cache version doesn't make any difference, but if that isn't the case you are cloning the A values from the first row on the following rows with same `b_id1`.